# PHP pdo exception "could not find driver" pgsql

Tags: php, postgresql, exception, pdo, driver

So i always get a pdo exception when i try to create my db in the constructor of my Mapper class.
on this line:

```
$this->db = new PDO($dsn, $db_config['username'], $db_config['password']);
```

this is my dsn creation:

```
    $db_config = array(
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'username' => $dbUser,
    'password' => $dbPassword,
    'schema' => 'r0628740',
    'dsn' => array(
        'host' => 'gegevensbanken.khleuven.be',
        'dbname' => '2TX31',
        'port' => '51314',
    )
);
```

and finaly my constructor:

```
public function __construct(){
        global $db_config;
        $dsn = $db_config['driver'] . ':';
        foreach($db_config['dsn'] as $key => $value){
            $dsn .= $key . '=' . $value . ';';
        }
        try{

            $this->db = new PDO($dsn, $db_config['username'], $db_config['password']);
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            if(($db_config['driver'] == 'pgsql') && isset($db_config['schema'])){
                $this->db->query(sprintf("SET SEARCH_PATH TO %s"), $db_config['schema']);
            }
        }catch (PDOException $e){
            var_dump($e->getLine());
            error_log($e->getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: my guess would be that the pgsql driver is not installed (or activated in the php configuration)

Comment: Maybe the PDO isn't visible at time of __construct... Or... what does phpinfo() return for the PDO?

Answer (score 2):

The PHP contains a dll required by pgsql and pgsql_pdo driver libpq.dll...
Add PHP binary path to system path or copy de DLL into Windows\system32. On linux dependency are installed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I found article somewhere, works for me. Assuming you have installed PostgreSQL and your WAMP installation is on `c:\wamp`, you will need to copy:

`c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\libpq.dll` to `c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin`.

Make sure you also have the following files:

`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\ext\php_pdo_pgsql.dll` and
`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\ext\php_pgsql.dll`

Also, make sure you have enabled the above 2 files as extensions, either via the WAMP menu (click on WAMP icon on taskbar: `PHP > PHP extensions`, find the above 2 and 'check' them).

Please note that `php5.3.9` and `Apache2.2.11` refer to my specific PHP and Apache versions.

Adjust those to suit your installation.

Answer (score 0):

Copying this ***libpq.dll*** from *c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\libpq.dll* to *c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin*. has worked for me